Multiply defined links to chapter and sections not working
I have a PhD thesis, originally written in English, and I am trying to include a translation of the thesis into Spanish in the same document. For the most part, this has been working well, but I am having an issue with the links to chapters and sections.
I would like both the English and Spanish version to use the same numbering system. However, when I click on the links to the Spanish language sections, it takes me to the corresponding English language sections. I would like these links to take me to the corresponding Spanish sections. The labels in the English and Spanish sections are already distinct from one another, so I suspect the issue is that the Chapter and Section numbers are multiply defined in the table of contents.
How can I write the code so that the numbering stays the same between both the Spanish and English versions, but so that the Spanish version's links take me to the correct sections and chapters in Spanish?
Below is my full code in the .tex file
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{tesis}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage[english,spanish,main=english,shorthands=off]{babel}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[labelfont={bf}]{caption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{changepage}  % for the adjustwidth environment
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2205}{\o}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0301}{\'{i}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0304}{\={}}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[scr=boondox]{mathalfa}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[obeyspaces,spaces]{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black,citecolor=black,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{float}

\title{Sociolinguistic Variation and Mentioned Ideology in the Spanish of Juchitán, México}
\carrera{Dissertation submitted in partial fulfilment of the requirements for the degree of Doctor in Philosophy}
\author{Craig Zachary Welker}
\emailauthor{\url{czwelker@gmail.com}}
\firstadvisor{Prof. Dr. Yvette Bürki}
\emailfirstadvisor{\url{yvette.buerki@unibe.ch}}
\secondadvisor{Prof. Dr. David Britain}
\emailsecondadvisor{\url{david.britain@unibe.ch}}
\firstadvisoresp{Profa. Dra. Yvette Bürki}
\titleesp{Variación sociolingüística e ideología mencionada en el español de Juchitán, México}
\carreraesp{Tesis presentada en cumplimiento parcial de los requisitos para la obtención del grado de Doctor en Filosofía}

\linespread{1.5}

\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-authoryear-comp, giveninits=false, natbib=true, sorting=nyt, uniquename=false, language=english, maxcitenames=2, dashed=false, innamebeforetitle=true]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\space}

\bibliography{References}

\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,inproceedings,incollection]{title}{#1\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1} (unpublished\nopunct}
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{booktitle}{#1\nopunct}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
 and       = {\&},
 in        = {},
 andothers = {et al.},
 volume    = {}
}

\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\hilight}[1]{\colorbox{yellow}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\portadilla

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents / Índice}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents / Índice}
\tableofcontents

\phantomsection
\newpage
\begin{agradeciments}
\end{agradeciments}

\input{Chapters/EnglishVersion}

\phantomsection
\begin{acknowledgements} 
\end{acknowledgements}

\phantomsection
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}

\phantomsection
\begin{terjemahan}
\end{terjemahan}

\mainmatter
\addtolength{\abovedisplayskip}{-1.1mm}
\addtolength{\belowdisplayskip}{-1.1mm}

\input{Chapters/Chapter1/Chapter1}
\input{Chapters/Chapter1/1.1}
\input{Chapters/Chapter1/1.2}
\input{Chapters/Chapter1/1.3}
\input{Chapters/Chapter1/1.4}
\input{Chapters/Chapter1/1.5}
\input{Chapters/Chapter1/1.6}
\input{Chapters/Chapter1/1.7}
\input{Chapters/Chapter2/Chapter2}
\input{Chapters/Chapter2/2.1}
\input{Chapters/Chapter2/2.2}
\input{Chapters/Chapter2/2.3}
\input{Chapters/Chapter2/2.4}
\input{Chapters/Chapter2/2.5}
\input{Chapters/Chapter2/2.6}
\input{Chapters/Chapter2/2.7}
\input{Chapters/Chapter2/2.8}
\input{Chapters/Chapter2/2.9}
\input{Chapters/Chapter3/Chapter3}
\input{Chapters/Chapter3/3.1}
\input{Chapters/Chapter3/3.2}
\input{Chapters/Chapter3/3.3a}
\input{Chapters/Chapter3/3.4a}
\input{Chapters/Chapter4/Chapter4}
\input{Chapters/Chapter4/4.1}
\input{Chapters/Chapter4/4.2}
\input{Chapters/Chapter4/4.3}
\input{Chapters/Chapter4/4.4}
\input{Chapters/Chapter4/4.5}
\input{Chapters/Chapter4/4.6}
\input{Chapters/Chapter4/5.1}
\input{Chapters/Chapter4/5.2}
\input{Chapters/Chapter4/5.3}
\input{Chapters/Chapter4/5.4}
\input{Chapters/Chapter6/Chapter6}
\input{Chapters/Chapter6/6.1}
\input{Chapters/Chapter6/6.2}
\input{Chapters/Chapter6/6.3}
\input{Chapters/Chapter6/6.4}
\input{Chapters/Chapter6/6.5}
\input{Chapters/Chapter6/6.6}
\input{Chapters/Chapter7/Chapter7}
\input{Chapters/Chapter7/7.1}
\input{Chapters/Chapter7/7.2}
\input{Chapters/Chapter7/7.3}
\input{Chapters/Chapter7/7.4}
\input{Chapters/Chapter7/7.5}
\input{Chapters/Chapter7/7.6}
\input{Chapters/Chapter7/7.7}
\input{Chapters/Chapter8/Chapter8}
\input{Chapters/Chapter8/8.1}
\input{Chapters/Chapter8/8.2}
\input{Chapters/Chapter8/8.3}
\input{Chapters/Chapter8/8.4}
\input{Chapters/Chapter8/8.5}
\input{Chapters/Chapter8/8.6}
\input{Chapters/Chapter9/Chapter9}
\input{Chapters/Chapter9/9.1}
\input{Chapters/Chapter9/9.2}
\input{Chapters/Chapter9/9.3}
\input{Chapters/Chapter9/9.4}
\input{Chapters/Chapter9/9.5}
\input{Chapters/Chapter10/Chapter10}
\input{Chapters/Chapter10/10.1}
\input{Chapters/Chapter10/10.2}
\input{Chapters/Chapter10/10.3}

\setcounter{page}{11}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\input{Capítulos/VersiónEspañola}

\portadillaesp 

\phantomsection
\begin{agradecimientos} 
\end{agradecimientos}

\phantomsection
\begin{resumen}
\end{resumen}

\phantomsection
\begin{terjemahann}
\end{terjemahann}

\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\setcounter{page}{0}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 1/Capítulo 1}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 1/1.1}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 1/1.2}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 1/1.3}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 1/1.4}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 1/1.5}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 1/1.6}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 1/1.7}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 2/Capítulo 2}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 2/2.1}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 2/2.2}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 2/2.3}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 2/2.4}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 2/2.5}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 2/2.6}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 2/2.7}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 2/2.8}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 2/2.9}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 3/Capítulo 3}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 3/3.1}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 3/3.2}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 3/3.3}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 3/3.4}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 4/Capítulo 4}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 4/4.1}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 4/4.2}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 4/4.3}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 4/4.4}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 4/4.5}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 4/4.6}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 4/5.1}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 4/5.2}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 4/5.3}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 4/5.4}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 6/Capítulo 6}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 6/6.1}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 6/6.2}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 6/6.3}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 6/6.4}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 6/6.5}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 6/6.6}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 7/Capítulo 7}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 7/7.1}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 7/7.2}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 7/7.3}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 7/7.4}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 7/7.5}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 7/7.6}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 7/7.7}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 8/Capítulo 8}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 8/8.1}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 8/8.2}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 8/8.3}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 8/8.4}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 8/8.5}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 8/8.6}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 9/Capítulo 9}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 9/9.1}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 9/9.2}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 9/9.3}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 9/9.4}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 9/9.5}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 10/Capítulo 10}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 10/10.1}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 10/10.2}
\input{Capítulos/Capítulo 10/10.3}

\selectlanguage{english}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References / Referencias}
\printbibliography[title = {References / Referencias}]

\setcounter{chapter}{10}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\input{Chapters/End:Appendices/Appendices}

\end{document}


A small example showing the problem would be more use to us (without  any  \input files).

Check out \HyperDestNameFilter on page 12 of the hyperref manual.

Thank you. I was able to fix the problem by consulting page 12 of the hyperref manual. Specifically, disabling hypertextnames fixed the issue. I replaced \usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black,citecolor=black,bookmarks=true]{hyperref} with \usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black,citecolor=black,bookmarks=true,hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}

Interesting.  I was thinking you could just add a prefix when you switched languages.  That way english would link to english and spansh would link to spanish.
